# Suspend kotlin coroutine async subfunction

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an async `CoroutineScope` in which could be (by condition) a call to a subfunction which returns its result in an async `Unit`

How can I wait for the returned result and return it outside of the async `Unit`. Therefore *await* the call to the `Unit` by the subfunction.

Example:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    var value: Int = 0
    if (condition) {
        // the subFunction has a Unit<Int> as return type
        subFunction() { result ->
            value = result
        }
    }
    Log.v("LOGTAG", value.toString())
}
```

How can I wait for the `subFunction` to finish executing before continuing the code, or directly assign the result value to the variable?

`subFunction` **must not** be a `suspend` function, however it could be embedded into a helper function.

*(the code has to run in an Android enviroment)*

Comment: You can't do that without it being a suspend function.

Comment: @Francesc is it somehow possible to create a local supend function which handles this? I can't modify `subFunction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, converting your callback to a suspend function

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    var value: Int = 0
    if (condition) {
        // the subFunction has a Unit<Int> as return type
        value = subFunctionSuspend()
    }
    Log.v("LOGTAG", value.toString())
}

suspend fun subFunctionSuspend() = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    subFunction() { result ->
        cont.resume(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I'm correct you can also just inline the `subFunctionSuspend`. but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Not very nice but working solution with channels:

```
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val channel = Channel<Int>()
        if (condition) {
            // the subFunction has a Unit<Int> as return type
            subFunction() { result ->
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    channel.send(result)
                    channel.close()
                }
            }
        }
        for (i in channel) {
            println(i)
        }
    }
```